# In what situation in Heroes Unlimited 2E Revised would someone choose Extraordinary Strength over Superhuman Strength?

Tags: optimization, palladium-system, heroes-unlimited

In the game Heroes unlimited there are two powers that grant you strength that are considered minor powers, for all intents and purposes these powers require the same investment during character creation, however they don't really seem to be equal in my eyes.. Those two powers are Extraordinary Physical Strength and Superhuman Strength.

**Extraordinary Physical Strength** has the following Benefits:
Increases Physical strength to 20+2d6. If Physical strength is higher than 20 already, add 2d6+6 to it. Character can Carry 100 times Physical strength in pounds and lift 200 times Physical strength in pounds.

**Superhuman Strength** confers the following Benefits:
Add 20+2d4 to your current Physical Strength Attribute.
Character can carry 200 times Physical Strength in pounds and lift 300 times Physical strength in pounds. Character fatigues at half the rate of normal humans.

Why would one ever choose the first over the latter, other than for character flavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If given a choice, there's no reason besides character concept to pick Extraordinary Physical Strength over Superhuman Strength

But, obviously, random determination means the player *doesn't* pick. Traditionally, what super abilities a character in *Heroes Unlimited* possesses are determined randomly, so it's possible a character may get stuck with the inferior Extraordinary Physical Strength minor super ability instead of the superior Superhuman Strength minor super ability.

When rolling minor super abilities on the Random Minor Super Abilities Table (227), there's a 3% chance of rolling the minor super ability **Superhuman Strength** (236) and a 3% chance of being redirected to the Extraordinary Attribute Sub-table (227). On that sub-table, there's an 11% chance of rolling **Extraordinary Physical Strength** (231), a 6% chance of rolling Superhuman Strength, and a 4% chance of rolling the major super ability **Supernatural Strength** (293-4).

### Supernatural Strength is a major super ability

Although it can be rolled on the Extraordinary Attribute Sub-table, the major super ability Supernatural Strength—which adds to +30+2d6 to a character's P.S., allows carrying ×300, and allows lifting ×500—should probably be unavailable as a minor super ability, even accidentally, unless one's *seriously* optimizing one's *Heroes Unlimited* character. Ask the GM about such a lucky roll.